# How can I avoid overlapping stroks cancelling each other? (Defect?)

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg

I have the following SVG in an HTML page.

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox="0 0 1 1">
    <circle class='spath' cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.02" stroke="green" stroke-width="0.08" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

The `stroke-width` is more than enough to cover the entire width of the circle. Instead of a solid circle though I get the following rendering:

[image]

Wherever the stroke overlaps itself from the other side it gets cancelled -- it draws nothing on the overlapping parts.

Is there some CSS/SVG setting to avoid this, or is it a Firefox rendering defect? (On Linux)

---

For reference, here is a `stroke-width="0.05"`, which should not be filling less of the circle (like 0.08, it should completely fill it).

[image]

And this is 0.4, the size required to fill the circle. Since it lacks any overlap it appears to draw correctly.

[image]

---

*Note*: I'm unable to workaround the problem by calculating the exact size required. This is just a reduced example with a simple path. My full SVG has many curves and different points of overlap.

Comment: Related: http://tavmjong.free.fr/blog/?p=1257

Comment: could be this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=896248

Comment: That looks like it's broken and there's nothing I can do.